# Write python 'pair of points' to Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-excel

I'm looking for a way to write a 'pair of points' to Excel.

Currently I've a script that writes the shortest distance between each point X of set A and any of the points Y of set B.

Is there a way to tweak this piece of the script to write the shortest distance pair to excel? (e.g. For point 3 from set A, point 29 from set B is the shortest --> (3,29)

```
def shortest_distance_pair(Comp, Net):
    pairs = []
    shortestfinal = []
    for P in Comp:
        shortest_distance = 999999
        for Y in Net:
            distance = CoordinatesDistance(P,Y)
            #customer_distance.append(distance)
            if distance < shortest_distance:
                shortest_distance = distance
                sdp = [(P,Y)]
            pairs.append(sdp)
        shortestfinal.append(shortest_distance)
    return shortestfinal

output = shortest_distance_pair(compco, networkco)


wb = Workbook(write_only = True) 
ws = wb.create_sheet() 

ws.append(output) 
wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

https://pastebin.com/X3s0ZLaH

Comment: Hi whats the output type? is it a `list` that contains just one `tuple`? `[(3,29)]`

Comment: Please add some Data to your Question for `compco, networkco` so we can run your Example.